# Maven build sub projects using root pom

Tags: maven

I have different independent maven projects and want to build it with single pom. So I am using following pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>a.b</groupId>
<artifactId>my-sdk</artifactId>
<name>my-sdk</name>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<description>Generating SDK</description>

<modules>
    <module>project1</module>
    <module>project2</module>
    <module>project3</module>
</modules>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process-sources</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <ant antfile="build.xml" target="init" />
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jboss-repo</id>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

I have the following questions:-

1. Javadoc is not generating, so where I am doing wrong. If I run "mvn javadoc:javadoc package" command it generates java doc. But if I run "mvn package" it doesn't.
2. In project2 there is assembly plugin to generate fat jar, it generates jar of project2 but unable to generate fat jar. If I build project2 independently it generate fat jar successfully.

Follwing section is from project2 pom to generate fat jar which works successfully if I run the build independently

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>[MAIN CLASS]</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                            <manifestEntries>
                                <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
                            </manifestEntries>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assembly</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any Suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say check the documentation for both of your questions ;-)

**javadoc** (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/plugin-info.html)

*javadoc:jar* and *javadoc:javadoc* should not be used for an aggregator project, use *javadoc:aggregate* or (in your case) *javadoc:aggregate-jar*

**assembly** (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly-mojo.html)

first, *assembly:assembly* is deprecated and second, it should only be used on the command line. I guess using goal *single* will help.

Comment: javadoc:aggregate generates the javadoc in a single folder for all projects but I want to generate javadoc for individual using root pom but ubable to do it.